# shiny disable tables in a specific navlistPanel

Tags: r, shiny

every one, I want to make a shiny app, which can disable tables in a specific navlistPanel, follow is my code which can disabe all the tabs in navlistPanel:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
useShinyjs(),
navlistPanel(id = "inTabset1",
               tabPanel(title = "Panel 1", value = "panel1",
                        actionButton('jumpToP2', 'Jump to Second Tab')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel 2", value = "panel2",
                        actionButton('jumpToP1', 'Jump to First Tab'))
               # tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav a {cursor: default}')))),
  navlistPanel(id = "inTabset2",
           tabPanel(title = "Panel 3", value = "panel3",
                    actionButton('jumpToP3', 'Jump to fouth Tab')),
           tabPanel(title = "Panel 4", value = "panel4",
                    actionButton('jumpToP4', 'Jump to third Tab'))
           # tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav a {cursor: default}')))))

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

# shinyjs::disable(selector = '.navbar-nav a'
  shinyjs::disable(
    # id = "inTabset1",
                   selector = '.nav li a'
                   )

observeEvent(input$jumpToP2, {
  updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset1",
                    selected = "panel2")
})

observeEvent(input$jumpToP1, {
  updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset1",
                    selected = "panel1")
})


observeEvent(input$jumpToP3, {
  updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset2",
                    selected = "panel4")
})

observeEvent(input$jumpToP4, {
  updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset2",
                    selected = "panel3")
})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Those code can disable all the tabs in two navlistPanle. However, when I want to only disable the tabs in the first navlistPanel, inTabset1, so I add the id to the function of disable like this:

```
     shinyjs::disable(
    id = "inTabset1",
                   selector = '.nav li a'
                   )
```

It did not work any more! All the tabs are not disabled! So any guys can help me for this question? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use both the arguments `id` and `selector` in `disable`, see the documentation for the function [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjs/shinyjs.pdf):

> **id**     The id of the input element/Shiny tag
>
> **selector**   Query selector of
>   the elements to target. Ignored if the id argument is given. For
>   example, to disable all text inputs, use selector =
>   "input[type='text']"

What you could do however, is change your selector to `'#inTabset1 li a'`, so it will disable all elements of class `a` that are in an element class `li` that are in the element with id `inTabset1`.

Here is a working example, I hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navlistPanel(id = "inTabset1",
               tabPanel(title = "Panel 1", value = "panel1",
                        actionButton('jumpToP2', 'Jump to Second Tab')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel 2", value = "panel2",
                        actionButton('jumpToP1', 'Jump to First Tab'))),
  # tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav a {cursor: default}')))),
  navlistPanel(id = "inTabset2",
               tabPanel(title = "Panel 3", value = "panel3",
                        actionButton('jumpToP3', 'Jump to fouth Tab')),
               tabPanel(title = "Panel 4", value = "panel4",
                        actionButton('jumpToP4', 'Jump to third Tab'))
               # tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav a {cursor: default}')))))

  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # shinyjs::disable(selector = '.navbar-nav a'
  shinyjs::disable(
    selector = '#inTabset1 li a'
  )

  observeEvent(input$jumpToP2, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset1",
                      selected = "panel2")
  })

  observeEvent(input$jumpToP1, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset1",
                      selected = "panel1")
  })


  observeEvent(input$jumpToP3, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset2",
                      selected = "panel4")
  })

  observeEvent(input$jumpToP4, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset2",
                      selected = "panel3")
  })}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, Florian. Thank you very much for your nice and helpful answer! This works!

Comment: Hi @JasperShen, Glad I could help. If you would please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark your question as resolved, that would be great, thanks!

Comment: OK, of course. I have accepted this answer. Thanks again.